# How to select SQL in mysql with complex condiction

Tags: mysql

In my project, I am in trouble in SQL for selecting.

I have a table A which has num ,name and stat fields.

```
select * from A;
```

The part of results are:

```
num   name  stat
1    flank  fin
2    lilei  fin
3    John   fin
1    flank  undo
1    John   fin
2    flank  fin
```

Now I want to select all num of flank which stat is fin.

I have tried:

```
select distinct num from A where name='flank' and stat is not in (select num from A where name='flank' and stat='undo');
```

It works fail for 'is no in'.

I tried another way for:

```
select distinct num from A where name='flank';//select all num of flank and stored in one[] array with php.
```

and then:

```
select distinct num from A where name='flank' and stat='undo';//select undo num of flank and stored in two[] array with php
```

finally I got correct result:

```
one[]-two[]//delect elements which in two array
```

But when the quantity of num is large, one[] array will overflow. At the same time, the efficiency of select is low.

So it fail again.

Who can help me?

Comment: Does a number match because it has _one_ `flank` name, or does _every_ name have to be `flank` in order for a number to be a match?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible interpretation of your question:

```
SELECT *
FROM A a1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT num
    FROM A
    GROUP BY num
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN stat = 'undo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) a2
    ON a1.num = a2.num
WHERE
    a1.name = 'flank';
```

Comment: the result is 'num'. When I use "select num" instead of "select *", it is wrong. I have got  Column 'num' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: see my own answer. Thankyou all the same

Answer (score 0):

the corrent soluction is :

```
SELECT num
FROM A
where name='flank'
GROUP BY num
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN stat = 'undo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```